# How to kill spawnSync after a timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, spawn

I want to kill the spawnSync process in ES6 async / await.

```
  (async () => {
    const type = 'python';
    const exefile = './test.py';
    let opt = [file];

    let result = await spawnSync(type, opt, {
      encoding: 'utf-8'
    });

    if (exefile !== '') {

      const exeRst = await spawnSync(exefile, {
        encoding: 'utf-8'
      });

      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('⏰ Timeout!!');
        console.log('exeResult.pid : ', exeResult.pid);
        exeResult.kill();
      }, 2000);

      if (
        result.output['1'] === '' &&
        result.output['2'] === '' &&
        exeRst.output['1'] !== ''
      ) {
        console.log('exeResult:', exeRst);
        console.log('result:', result.output);
      }
    }
  })();
```

If the second spawnSync exeRst takes a long time, it will stop executing within 2 seconds.

test.py takes 10 seconds or more to run.

However, due to await, setTimeout will be executed after 10 seconds after all the execution of test.py has ended.

How do I make it impossible to run for more than 2 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[spawnSync](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options) supports an option field called `timeout`. This specifies in milliseconds how long the process is allowed to run:

```
await spawnSync(exefile, {
        encoding: 'utf-8',
        timeout: 2000
      });
```

Comment: Wow!!  It was in node.js document.
Thank you for your clear answer.